# JPA Criteria Query with predicate that compares a field annotated @Convert gets a ORA-00932 upon execution

Tags: java, oracle11g, jpa-2.1, ora-00932

I'm developing a Java EE 7 application (persistence provider is Hibernate 4.3.5, DB is Oracle 11g) in which I'm using a entity class with a Long field that represents the millis of a date. It's been done that way to avoid the problems of using DBs' date datatypes (e.g. timezone handling). Here's the relevant entity class code:

```
import java.util.Date;

@Table
@Entity
public class Transference implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // ... elided fields

    private Date dateTime;

    // ... elided setters and getters

    @Column(name = "datetime")
    @Convert(converter = DateConverter.class)
    @NotNull
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

}
```

Attribute in the metamodel class:

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Transference, Date> dateTime;
```

Here's the straightforward JPA 2.1 converter:

```
import java.util.Date;

@Converter
public class DateConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(Date attribute) {
        return (attribute == null)? null : attribute.getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(Long dbData) {
        return dbData == null? null : new Date(dbData);
    }

}
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE transference (
-- fields ...
datetime NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
-- constraints...
);
```

Persisting and reading the field value works like a charm. The problem comes when I try to use a predicate in a CriteriaQuery that compares the field with a value:

```
private List<Transference> queryResultList() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Transference> cq = cb.createQuery(Transference.class);
    Root<Transference> root = cq.from(Transference.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    // Predicates with other fields...

    if (this.dateTo != null) {
        Path<Date> pathDateTo = root.get(Transference_.dateTime);
        Predicate predDateTo = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(pathDateTo, this.dateTo);
        predicates.add(predDateTo);
    }

    Order orderBy = cb.desc(root.get(Transference_.dateTime));
    Predicate[] predicatesArray = {};

    cq.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(predicatesArray)).orderBy(orderBy);

    TypedQuery<Transference> tq = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return tq.getResultList();  // <- A exception is thrown here, when predDateTo is used in the query.

}
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP
```

Stacktrace:

```
22:04:12,286 WARN  [SqlExceptionHelper] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:144) SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
22:04:12,288 ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:146) ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP

22:04:12,289 INFO  [JdbcCoordinatorImpl] (JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:298) HHH000106: Forcing container resource cleanup on transaction completion
22:04:12,290 SEVERE [application] (FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1224) Error Rendering View[/ctr.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /ctr.xhtml @118,47 value="#{consultaTransferencias.resultList}": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    ...
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... <my code calls>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.interceptorChainCompleted(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:52) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:83) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:41) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    ... <my code calls>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502) [ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 121 more

22:04:12,309 SEVERE [context] (AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:218) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    ... <my code calls>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.interceptorChainCompleted(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53)
    .. <my code calls>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:629)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:758)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:740)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:264)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:226)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1864)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:599)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:406)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:325)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:435)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.render(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:111)
    at javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:92)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 121 more
```

*What is the right way to use such a field in a criteria query predicate?* The converter only works for reading/persisting. I've been looking for a way and been unable to, even in the JPA 2.1 specification (which is very large, by the way). What am I missing here? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the long value .getTime() instead of date to check?

Comment: You mean

Predicate predDateTo = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(pathDateTo, this.dateTo.getTime());

?

It won't work, compiler complains (obviously): Bound mismatch: The generic method lessThanOrEqualTo(Expression<? extends Y>, Y) of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Date>, Long). The inferred type Object&Serializable&Comparable<?> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Y extends Comparable<? super Y>>. The expected type is Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your kind answers. I couldn't figure out how to use the field, but I came up with this (not so pretty) workaround:

```
private Date dateTime; // Original field
private Long dateTimeMillis;

@Column(name = "datetime")
@NotNull
@Convert(converter = DateConverter.class)
public Date getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

// Another mapping for the datetime column, will use this for criteria queries:
@Column(name = "datetime", updatable = false, insertable = false)
public Long getDateTimeMillis() {
    return dateTimeMillis;
}
```

Predicate:

```
Path<Long> pathDateTo = root.get(Transference_.dateTimeMillis);
Predicate predDateTo = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(pathDateTo, this.dateTo.getTime());
predicates.add(predDateTo);
```

Then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For timezone handling, you can save date in UTC timezone in all databases and in java convert to specific timezone. Java has internalization concept to handle these issue. Please refer to following link for more details : [Java Date And Time internalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateintro.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, I actually have another column to store the timezone, but that is not the point of the question. But thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be: add the annotation to your date field, it will convert the long timestamp to date

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Your code should look like

```
@Column(name = "datetime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
@NotNull
public Date getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The table field is a NUMBER(20), and I get ORA-00932 at persist time.